# Continue executing bash script after a build command

Tags: bash

I have a script that installs jdk in ubuntu and sets java_home path. After installing and setting the jdk,i want to compile some java code and then send some emails notifying me that the build is complete. Below is some pseudo code

```
#!/bin/bash          
sudo apt-get jdk
javac app.java
echo Build complete
function smail {
sendlogic
}
smail
echo Mail sent
```

I know the compiling can take up to 10 minutes. Am i guaranteed that the bash script will continue executing even after the build takes 10 minutes which to me is a long time?.

Second,what if the building has errors, is there a way i can catch that in my bash script?.

Comment: Why would how long a command takes have anything to do with whether the enclosing script continues to run after that command is complete?

Comment: I pay the server by the hour so i thought it was a factor i should keep in mind.

Comment: I would suggest posting your real script, the example you've posted is meaningless to your question.

Comment: The script i have only does the java compiling. Of interest is how i would catch build failed from bash.

Comment: `bash` itself has no time limit. If you are concerned your hosting provider will terminate the script, you'll need to ask them.

Comment: BTW, `function smail { sendlogic; }` is a needlessly unportable way to do a function definition. If you instead used `smail() { sendlogic; }`, that would work with all POSIX-compliant shells, not just bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A process will run until it completes unless interrupted or a signal is received to abort.

When attempting to identify if a process completed successfully you can often check the exit status of a processes immediately after it completed with a special command '$?'. This command will display a value, 0 normally meaning successful. Other numbers may represent something failed and are usually defined uniquely by the command or program. If you are writing a program or script you can send these values using the 'exit' command in your program. Your script can also use the exit status to determine how to handle the fail.

Comment: Explicitly checking `$?` is actually bad practice in the general case -- it's better to run `if ! some_command; then ...`, or `some_command || { echo "some_command failed" >&2; exit 1; }` or such than to run `some_command; if (( $? != 0 )); then ...; fi`.